# Displaying available methods in constructor help file for user-created MATLAB objects

Tags: matlab, oop, documentation

I want to add a help file to an object (call it "myobject") I created in MATLAB, but I also want the methods available to that object to be shown when I type "help myobject"

For example, if I leave the help portion of the code blank, typing "help myobject" yields:

```
>> help myobject
myobject methods:

mymethod1             - This is the first method available for myobject
mymethod2             - This is the second available method for myobject
```

However, if I add text to the constructor to explain what the object is and how it should be used, then typing "help myobject" yields:

```
>> help myobject
This is the text telling you about myobject and how it should be used.
```

I want to both be able to have the written text describing myobject, as well as a live query of the methods available to myobject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the MATLAB help system doesn't do this for you automatically, you need to keep the help up-to-date yourself. If you format the class help correctly, it gets magically hyperlinked - try "edit table" in R2013b or "edit containers.Map" in earlier releases to see what can be done.

Also note that you can document the class separately from the constructor, like so:

```matlab
%MYOBJECT - object of mine
%   This is the class help
%   more class help...
%
%   MYOBJECT methods:
%      doStuff - does stuff   
%
% See also myobject/myobject.

classdef myobject
    methods
        function obj = myobject(arg1, arg2)
        %MYOBJECT - construct my object
        %   OBJ = MYOBJECT(ARG1) builds an object based on ARG1.
        %
        %   OBJ = MYOBJECT(ARG1,ARG2) builds an object based on ARG1 and ARG2.

        ...
        end
    end
end
```

And then you can do

```
>> help myobject % class help
>> help myobject/myobject % constructor help
```